# Efficient way to map numbers 1 to 1 in a pseudorandom manner?

Tags: algorithm, math, api-design

I don't want to return raw user IDs to the frontend. A lot of people solve this by generating random IDs and checking if they're already in the DB. I want to find a way to map numbers in a known range 1 to 1. This way, I can still use auto-incremented IDs internally, but return the pseudorandomly mapped IDs to the frontend.

I could just shuffle all numbers from 1 to N in a deterministic way, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: Have you considered UUID? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: UUIDs are what I described, you generate a random number and check if it's already in the DB, I'd prefer a cleaner mathematical way to do it

Comment: The easiest way is to put the number through some block cipher. Block ciphers are essentially keyed shuffle functions.

Answer (score -1):

You can pick a random number and use bitwise XOR operations to switch between frontend and database IDs.

It would probably be easy to reverse engineer, but it's very easy to use.

Here's an example in JavaScript:

```js
const seed = 123;
const internalIds = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(internalIds.join(','));
const frontIds = internalIds.map(id => id ^ seed);
console.log(frontIds.join(','));
const recoveredIds = frontIds.map(id => id ^ seed);
console.log(recoveredIds.join(','));
```

Comment: Can I have some insight about why this answer is downvoted? Did I miss something?